# show that set is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider set $A= \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2+\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ show that $A$ is countable

To show that we need to show that $A$ is infinite and $|A|\le|B|$ where $|B|=|\mathbb{N}|$

to it's infinite we can consider $x=a-{\sqrt{2}}b$ and $a\cdot b=\frac{1}{2}$ then $x^2+\sqrt{2}=a^2+2b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$

any ideas how find injection $A \to B$  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $ f(x)  = x^2 + \sqrt{2}$ is injective if we consider it on two disjoint sets $ (-\infty, 0] $ and $ (0,\infty) $.

It means that we can split $ A $ in two pieces:

$$ A = A_1\cup A_2 , ~~A_1 = A\cap(-\infty, 0], A_2 = A \cap (0,\infty) $$

and for both $ i = 1,2 $ we can define an injection:

$$ A_i \ni x \rightarrow x^2 + \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q} $$

So $ A $ is a sum of two countable sets, therefore it's countable

Comment: I don't see how works our defined injection, when $x$ goes to $A_1$ and when to $A_2$ ?

Comment: I am proving that $ A_1, A_2 $ are both (at most) countable, by giving a formula for the injection for each of them (two incjections: $f_1 : A_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} $  and $ f_2 : A_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} $, it's just their formula is the same)